# "Were that you who did that" vs. "was that you who did that"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, british-english, verb-agreement

Which of the following is correct?

> - Were that you who did that?
> - Was that you who did that?

Obviously one has to use *were* with *you*, but which one goes here in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The subject of the main clause is *that*, singular. It follows that the verb has to be *was*, also singular.

Comment: Spot on, thanks. Knew the answer but just wanted to add something to the community and didn't know where to start.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky You can start on [ell.se] take a look.

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean to imply that I was learning English. I'm a native speaker.

Comment: Well so please do not ask questions because you have to ask a question!

Comment: This question has actually helped me to make sure I was wrong writing to my friend "that were you" and feeling it was not right but having no reference online. So, good question, good answer ;)